# Unable to start cygwin sshd service

Tags: hadoop, cygwin, sshd

I entered `ssh-host-config` into the cygwin prompt (started with admin privileges), said yes to privilege separation, new local account sshd, install sshd as a service; I entered no value for CYGWIN for daemon; I entered no for using a different name; yes for creating new privilege user account.

In my `services.msc` I am unable to start the service:

```
The CYGWIN sshd service on Local Computer started and then stopped. 
Some services stop automatically if they are not in use by other services
or programs.
```

In the cygwin prompt, `net start sshd` produces:

```
The CYGWIN sshd service could not be started. 
The service did not report an error.
More help is available by typing NET HELPMSG 3534
```

In the cygwin prompt, `cygrunsrv -S sshd` produces:

```
cygrunsrv: Error starting a service: QueryServiceStatus:  Win32 error 1062:
The service has not been started.
```

My /var/log/sshd.log says the following:

```
Unable to initialize device PRN
```

I've searched the questions on SO related to this issue, as well as the general Internet, and I guess what makes my question unique has to do with the sshd.log. I can't find anyone else who has received this.

I'm doing this to install Hadoop on my Windows. I cannot run a virtual machine on this slow computer as everything just bogs down.

Comment: I have exactly same problem in windows 7. I've followed various link but the problem still exists. Some of the links I've followed are: http://ebiquity.umbc.edu/Tutorials/Hadoop/00%20-%20Intro.html, https://gist.github.com/tariqmislam/2159173. Anybody reading this kindly provide a solution.

Answer (score 20):

I followed the steps in this topic and the problem was still happening, then I checked the sshd log file and it was complaining that the privilegies of the ssh private key were to open.

I executed the follow command:

```
chmod 400 /etc/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
```

Then I run the service:

```
net start sshd
```

It finally worked *(BTW: I am using Windows 8)*

Comment: Thank you for the answer. This works on Windows 8.1 as well. I will upvote the answer.

Comment: `chmod -v 600 /etc/ssh_*_key ; ls -altr  /etc/ssh*key` in my case, There were four.  Something about the Polish version of Win 8.1 lead to rw perms globally for group, in Cygwin.  `CYGWIN=ntsec`

Comment: you said you followed the steps in this topic, that is not meaningful, can you elaborate, if not, you should have at the time.

Comment: Worked on windows 7 as well. Only thing that worked for me after trying everything for 6 hours

Comment: This solved the problem in my case. I deleted all the keys and config files, and run `ssh-host-config` again.

Answer (score 16):

I had the same problem and here is the solution that worked for me.

**Solution 1**

Restart the machine after you set the path environment variables to point to Cygwin bin directories and then start the service.

**Solution 2**

1. First add the account that runs the Cygwin sshd demon service to administrators group (this is by default)
2. Go to your cygwin installation folder (mine is at c:\cygwin64 and yours may differ)

   - add administrators group as full control.   remove the property
   - Remove Readonly for your cygwin installation folder so anyone can write into it
3. Run the cygwin terminal as administrator and remove the service by typing

   ```
   cygrunsrv -R sshd
   ```
4. Reboot your system
5. Run the cygwin terminal as administrator and reinstall the service again by typing

   ```
   ssh-host-config -y
   ```
6. Run the cygwin terminal as administrator and start the service by typing

   ```
   net start sshd
   ```

Your service now be running!

Comment: I am on Windows 10. I do not see administrators group in Properties > Security. I do not see "read only" option.

I get an error on step 3

```
$ cygrunsrv -R sshd
cygrunsrv: Error removing a service: OpenService:  Win32 error 1060:
The specified service does not exist as an installed service.
```

Answer (score 5):

I tried above solutions but nothing worked for me.
I am using Windows 8 and was able to solve it.
My sshd.log file says : "Privilege separation user sshd does not exist FAILED"

So to remove this error while starting sshd as service just following below steps:

1. Edit the file /etc/passwd --
   add " sshd:x:74:74:Privilege-separated SSH:/var/empty/sshd:/sbin/nologin ".
2. Edit the file /etc/group -- 
   add " sshd:x:74: ".

Now start service as 
net start sshd

It worked for me!

Comment: Do you know why this works? How did you discover it?

Comment: Editing (creating acutally) the passwd file worked for me to solve this problem for the sshd that came with  (2.7.3) 64-bit version of Git for Windows.  (After 15 years of using Cygwin I gave it up a few months ago in favor of the utilities that come with Git and I don't miss it at all) I did not have to edit/create a group file. The only additional thing I had to do was mkdir /var/empty

Answer (score 2):

Followed the steps provide by Andrea Solution 1 and solution 2 , it did not work. Event viewer did not provide any info.

So took a look at the log var/log/sshd.log first it complained that it was unable to load the dll:

```
/usr/sbin/sshd.exe: error while loading shared libraries: cygcrypto-1.0.0.dll
```

Solution:

- Reinstalled the package and ensured that the dll were in lib.
- Started the service again still it failed but this time it complained about missing host key.

  Could not load host key: /etc/ssh_host_dsa_key
  Could not load host key: /etc/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
  Disabling protocol version 2. Could not load host key
  sshd: no hostkeys available -- exiting.

Solution:

- go to the Cygwin Command prompt (with run as admin ) and
- enter `ssh-keygen -A`
  the missing host key were generated .

Finally I was able to start it.

I would recommend looking at the log file further if the above solution does not work.

Comment: Yes!!! **Definitely do take a look** at `var/log/sshd.log!` My error was "Privilege separation user sshd does not exist" so I ran ssh-host-config again to enable the Privilege separation :)

Answer (score 0):

In my case (using a Polish version of Windows 8) I had to manually modify the /etc/passwd and /etc/group files.

Some lines for Administrator, Administrators, Guest, Guests, etc. had been missing, so I merely inserted them, and copied all other fields from their non-English versions.  Eg.

```
nano   /etc/passwd

SYSTEM:*:18:544:,S-1-5-18::
LocalService:*:19:544:U-NT AUTHORITY\LocalService,S-1-5-19::
NetworkService:*:20:544:U-NT AUTHORITY\NetworkService,S-1-5-20::
Administrators:*:544:544:,S-1-5-32-544::
Administratorzy:*:544:544:,S-1-5-32-544::
TrustedInstaller:*:4294967294:4294967294:U-NT SERVICE\TrustedInstaller,S-1-5-80-956008885-3418522649-1831038044-1853292631-2271478464::
Administrator:unused:500:513:U-gordito\Administrator,S-1-5-21-580982140-4090956935-1935414389-500:/home/Administrator:/bin/bash
Guest:unused:501:513:U-gordito\Gość,S-1-5-21-580982140-4090956935-1935414389-501:/home/Gość:/bin/bash
Gość:unused:501:513:U-gordito\Gość,S-1-5-21-580982140-4090956935-1935414389-501:/home/Gość:/bin/bash
HomeGroupUser$:unused:1004:513:HomeGroupUser$,U-gordito\HomeGroupUser$,S-1-5-21-580982140-4090956935-1935414389-1004:/home/HomeGroupUser$:/bin/bash
sshd:unused:1006:513:sshd privsep,U-gordito\sshd,S-1-5-21-580982140-4090956935-1935414389-1006:/var/empty:/bin/false
cyg_server:unused:1007:513:Privileged server,U-gordito\cyg_server,S-1-5-21-580982140-4090956935-1935414389-1007:/var/empty:/bin/false


nano /etc/group

root:S-1-5-32-544:0:
SYSTEM:S-1-5-18:18:
TrustedInstaller:S-1-5-80-956008885-3418522649-1831038044-1853292631-2271478464:4294967294:
Administrators:S-1-5-32-544:544:
Administratorzy:S-1-5-32-544:544:
Czytelnicy dzienników zdarzeń:S-1-5-32-573:573:
Guests:S-1-5-32-546:546:
Goście:S-1-5-32-546:546:
IIS_IUSRS:S-1-5-32-568:568:
Users:S-1-5-32-545:545:
Users DCOM:S-1-5-32-562:562:
Użytkownicy:S-1-5-32-545:545:
Użytkownicy DCOM:S-1-5-32-562:562:
Użytkownicy dzienników wydajności:S-1-5-32-559:559:
Użytkownicy monitora wydajności:S-1-5-32-558:558:
Użytkownicy zarządzania zdalnego:S-1-5-32-580:580:
HomeUsers:S-1-5-21-580982140-4090956935-1935414389-1003:1003:
TelnetClients:S-1-5-21-580982140-4090956935-1935414389-1005:1005:
WinRMRemoteWMIUsers__:S-1-5-21-580982140-4090956935-1935414389-1000:1000:
None:S-1-5-21-580982140-4090956935-1935414389-513:513:
Brak:S-1-5-21-580982140-4090956935-1935414389-513:513:
```

Only after this, I was finally able to `chmod g-rwx` all the files that offended sshd, in a way that 'ls -la' indeed confirmed the dropped permissions for group and other.

Then finally, privileged CYGWIN services installed and started (sshd, cron)

Comment: I see this as a Cygwin installation bug, anyway. Above is a workaround....once someone finally becomes aware what is really going on.