# Cant ssh to a cygwin server

Tags: cygwin

Its getting stuck as you can see.
Below is what verbose connection shows.

```
[ftpuser@eu9sacovn48 ~]$ ssh -v gmrsops@uscasaciccx82
OpenSSH_4.3p2, OpenSSL 0.9.8e-fips-rhel5 01 Jul 2008
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to uscasaciccx82 [113.130.154.54] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /cpmapps/ftpuser/.ssh/identity type -1
debug1: identity file /cpmapps/ftpuser/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: identity file /cpmapps/ftpuser/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: loaded 3 keys
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.6.1
debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.6.1 pat OpenSSH*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_4.3
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Host 'uscasaciccx82' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /cpmapps/ftpuser/.ssh/known_hosts:7
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /cpmapps/ftpuser/.ssh/identity
debug1: Offering public key: /cpmapps/ftpuser/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-rsa blen 277
debug1: read PEM private key done: type RSA
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: Sending environment.
debug1: Sending env LANG = en_US.UTF-8
```

I tried connecting to the server without a key but its still not working.

`[ftpuser@eu9sacovn48 ~]$ ssh -o PreferredAuthentications=keyboard-interactive,password -o PubkeyAuthentication=no gmrsops@USCASACICCX82
gmrsops@uscasaciccx82's password:`

I can login to cygwin just fine while on local server.

[image: local server]

Comment: What exactly do you mean when you say it's getting stuck?

Comment: Its never shows the screen where it says that it is connected to the remote server.

Comment: Are you sure the ssh server is running?

Comment: @McGlothlin: The debug output says that the public key authentication succeeded, so the server is likely running.

Comment: Latest cygwin ssh server is version 7.5p1. How updated is the cygwin machine ? Look also on ssh server application logs (usually on Event viewer, Windows log, Application, source=sshd)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to start cygwin sshd service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17736096/unable-to-start-cygwin-sshd-service)

Answer (score 1):

Here's what fixed the issue for me.

```
Run sshd in debug mode using below command

/usr/sbin/sshd.exe -D -dd
```

This gave me the below warnings

> $ /usr/sbin/sshd.exe -D -dd debug2: load_server_config: filename
>   /etc/sshd_config debug2: load_server_config: done config len = 285
>   debug2: parse_server_config: config /etc/sshd_config len 285 debug1:
>   sshd version OpenSSH_7.5, OpenSSL 1.0.2k  26 Jan 2017
>   @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@ @
>   WARNING: UNPROTECTED PRIVATE KEY FILE!          @
>   @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
>   Permissions 0770 for '/etc/ssh_host_rsa_key' are too open. It is
>   required that your private key files are NOT accessible by others.
>   This private key will be ignored. key_load_private: bad permissions
>   Could not load host key: /etc/ssh_host_rsa_key
>   @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@ @
>   WARNING: UNPROTECTED PRIVATE KEY FILE!          @
>   @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
>   Permissions 0770 for '/etc/ssh_host_dsa_key' are too open. It is
>   required that your private key files are NOT accessible by others.
>   This private key will be ignored. key_load_private: bad permissions
>   Could not load host key: /etc/ssh_host_dsa_key
>   @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@ @
>   WARNING: UNPROTECTED PRIVATE KEY FILE!          @
>   @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
>   Permissions 0770 for '/etc/ssh_host_ecdsa_key' are too open. It is
>   required that your private key files are NOT accessible by others.
>   This private key will be ignored. key_load_private: bad permissions
>   Could not load host key: /etc/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
>   @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@ @
>   WARNING: UNPROTECTED PRIVATE KEY FILE!          @
>   @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
>   Permissions 0770 for '/etc/ssh_host_ed25519_key' are too open. It is
>   required that your private key files are NOT accessible by others.
>   This private key will be ignored. key_load_private: bad permissions
>   Could not load host key: /etc/ssh_host_ed25519_key sshd: no hostkeys
>   available -- exiting.

```
So I changed the permissions of the above files to 600

$ chmod 0600 /etc/ssh_host*

Then the debug command again.

SHA256:4yqAb/GiMfMJPmIXfKz+Zw4fWOCVN7E6vUDHEtokdHk /var/empty must be owned by root and not group or world-writable.
```

Then change the permission of this folder to 600.

$ chmod 600 /var/empty

This fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're trying to connect to a Windows machine, you may not have an SSH server installed/enabled. Check to make sure SSH is installed and properly configured in your cygwin environment. It is part of the OpenSSH package. More info [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24628_01/install.121/e22624/preinstall_req_cygwin_ssh.htm#EMBSC150).

Edit: [See this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/626372/could-not-load-host-key-etc-ssh-ssh-host-ed25519-key-in-var-log-auth-log) where someone had the exact same error.

Comment: SSH server is installed fine as it was working fine 2 days ago. I checked the log and this is what its showing. I don't see a time stamp in the log but time stamp for the log file is  from them time when I restarted cygwin.


Could not load host key: /etc/ssh_host_ed25519_key
Could not load host key: /etc/ssh_host_ed25519_key
Could not load host key: /etc/ssh_host_ed25519_key
Could not load host key: /etc/ssh_host_ed25519_key
Could not load host key: /etc/ssh_host_ed25519_key
Could not load host key: /etc/ssh_host_ed25519_key

Comment: Updated answer. Potentially more help found here: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/ubuntu-sftp-ssh-access-work-but-got-error-could-not-load-host-key-in-log